# MEL: How do I select an end effector of a particular IK handle?

Tags: maya, mel

Everytime I create a new IK handle in Maya via MEL, it creates an end effector named "effector1", or "effector2", depending on what is in my scene.  I don't want to rely on the auto-name of the end effector, so I'm wondering if there is a way to either:

a) name the effector at the create-time of the IK handle, or

b) select the effector for a particular IK handle in MEL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -- thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can get and rename the end effector of a particular handle named ikHandle1:

```
string $ee = `ikHandle -q -endEffector ikHandle1`; 
// Result: effector1 //  
rename $ee "mynewname"; 
// Result: mynewname //
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late , but I made a new script with the help of kb's answer to rename it according to what's already been named. Just in case anyone comes across this in the future.

```
//selects all IKHandles
select `ls -type ikHandle`;
//stores them in an array
string $handles[] = `ls -sl`;

//for each item in the array,
for($handle in $handles)
{
    //create a new name by adding "_effector" to the end
    string $newName = ($handle + "_effector");        
    //find the effector and store that name in a variable
    string $efName = `ikHandle -q -endEffector $handle`; 
    //rename the effector
    rename $efName $newName;

}
```

if you don't want to rename *all* the IK handles, simply comment out the first line of code,

```
select `ls -type ikHandle`;
```

select all the handles you want to rename and run the code.